# Creating a Quiz

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to create a simple quiz of simple addition. I wanted to have 5 questions answered and then have a score of how the user did.

I would like to have it be like the following:
start -> Q1-Q2-Q3-Q4-Q5 -> Score

I have created the layout for Start and the Problems and Scoring.

So Start Activity would launch Problem Activity(reused for Q1 thru Q5) and once done then call displayScoreActivity.

How would I do such a thing???

Comment: This sounds really basic. It also sounds like you get the concept, but you don't know how to program it. A great place to start is http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html.

Comment: Just googled take a look at some example, try by yourself and if you find any problem then post on SO. Also you have to know which type of question ask on SO.

Comment: Do your work your self buddy.if you don't know how to do this then follow @Phil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)Create Start Activity .
2)Create Problem Activity with a ViewFlipper . flip all 5 questions .
maintain `int questionNo`. 
when all 5 questions answer
3)go to Score Activity

Comment: I am glad that you actually understood what I was referring too like the people above me. I will look into a ViewFlipper and see if that will work or not.